# How do I add some external executable to a Borland C++ Builder 2010 project?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++builder, c++builder-2010

So the question is how to add to c++ builder 2010 some external .exe file? Let's say that i made some program in visual basic and have the exe file, so that does not need to make the same code in c++ i want to just include that exe in my project? Is it possible to make portable application one exe that have inside him self another exe file (maybe in resource path)?
How to call it in code if it is one exe in other? I know to call it by system function, or other by putting direction to the exe, but how to do that if it is on same address as are main exe?

Comment: In general you should instead create a dll with the code you want to call. Notice however that it's much simpler to call C++ code from VB than the contrary.

Comment: the exe of visual basic is said just for example, the main point is that i don't know (or don't wannt to know) the function which is used in exe, i just need the final result of execution, let's say that is exe maked by assembly programing, and i just wannt to use the functionallity of that exe, don't wannt to study the source code of that exe ...

Comment: then use WinApi's function CreateProcess. it returns handles to spawned process's stdin and stdout.
you may just read all data from program's stdout using them.

Comment: @Raiv: No, it does not return handles to that effect. You have to create the handles yourself.

Comment: yes, but where to load or include wannted exe file in project, on resource or where?

Comment: @Raptor: No need to include it in the project. Just bundle it alongside your C++ builder executable. If you want to be able to deploy as one file just zip them up into an archive.

Comment: yes thnx, but what if i wannt to make portable application which make just one exe file will be everything work fine?

Comment: You could add the file as a resource and extract it upon execution.

Comment: @Raptor: The way I would do that would be to have some form of self extracting archive. If you bundle it as a resource (as @TommyA suggests) then you are going to have to extract it to the filesystem at some point, which users often find annoying (i.e. Where did this program come from). A self extractor will dump your program and dependencies into a temporary directory somewhere, and will automatically clean up for you when you're done running.

Comment: yes, but in that case i will have more than one exe file, which is of course not problem, i didn't understand how to extract resource upon execution. For example let's say that i have vcl form application whith one button and i also include vb exe in resource (who is let's say open notepad), so what code use to self extracting it? What code to put on button click event to execute vb exe?

Comment: Use the `TResourceStream` class to access the stored resource data, then use use a `TFileStream` (via its `CopyFrom()` method) to save the resource data to a file, and then lastly use `CreateProcess()` to execute the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to use the functionality of a given program, you're going to have to know things about how that program works.

If you want to take a given executable, and call it as you would a shell script, then you would need to start the given program with it's standard input and standard output redirected to a pipe. [An example of how to do that is available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx). If you want to be able to just look at the Visual Basic classes and methods in the target EXE, as you could do with Visual Basic .NET, you are out of luck, as an arbitrary executable does not understand the concept of a class or method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Project > Resources` dialog to add the VB .exe file to your project and give it an ID.  At runtime, your C++ code can then extract the resource data for that ID to a temporary file, such as with `TResourceStream` and `TFileStream`, and then use `CreateProcess()` to run it.  Don't forget to delete the file when you are done using it.

Otherwise, re-write the VB code into a DLL instead, and then the C++ app can simply call the DLL's exported functions when needed.  If you want to ship a single self-contained .exe (which is generally not how DLLs are used), then you will have to use the same resource approach, just use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`, instead of `CreateProcess()`, to access the DLL functions dynamically.